# Is there a way to deserialize only a single JSON field

Tags: c#, json, http, deserialization, httpresponse

I'm working on C#. From an API I get the following JSON response:

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Contraseña modificada correctamente",
    "aux": "{\"usId\":52,\"usLogin\":\"esther\",\"usNombre\":\"Esther\",\"usPass\":\"6074c6aa3488f3c2dddff2a7ca821aab\",\"usgId\":103}",
    "extra": null
}
```

Is there a way to deserialize only the `"aux"` field without deserializing all the JSON file? I want to avoid to create an object for the entire response because I only need the user included in the `"aux"`.

Comment: JObject.Parse(json)["aux"];

Comment: You could create a class with just that property